# How to sum several bracket-surrounded numbers of a single cell with Excel formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I have one cell containing several lines, including numbers inside brackets, which I want to sum-up with a single Excel formula (**no** VBA).

The following approach already works for single bracket:
https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-text-between-parentheses

But I need extended approach... here an example for the **content of one single Excel cell** to which I search for an formula, which should result in sum of "8":

```
The task requires following effort (incl. documentation)
- create plan (2h)
- execute test (14h)
- write report (draft) (2h)
```

Possible approach: The formula should search for all numbers inside the mask <"(" x "h)">, where x must be summed-up.

UPDATE: The formula should also work with numbers >=10.

UPDATE2: It should also work in case there are other comments in brackets, also after presence of first (xh) number. See "(draft)" in example, last row.

Comment: Are you looking for a single cell formula or is it okay to break this up over a few columns/cells?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor I am looking for a single cell formula, which is located next to the source cell (see example above). It would be ok to have another cell in same row (I could hide this cell), but it must not be distributed over several rows.

Comment: So if you are saying you could have another cell you could hide then it can be over several cells? Just as long as you have source cell, final formula cell next to it, then several hidden calculation cells?

Comment: @Chris Oh I can do it over several columns in the same row that can be hidden. I know that I can do that... I'll have a go at a single formula once I finish my work for the day then. I'm guessing there could be any number of `"(?h)"`s in the string or is there a definite maximum number?

Comment: Are you ever going to get a number in the first set of brackets? like (Include 2 documents)? Or would you get something other than hours like create plan (30mins)?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Yes, any number ist possible.

Comment: @ChrisM It could happen, that there is no number in first or any bracket. So only where the mask "("+x+"h)" exists, is a number to sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrow the formula from this post #6 (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/362184-extracting-multiple-numbers-string.html) and modified to fit your need (single cell formula).  Assuming you are going to enter the formula in `cell B1`:

```
{=SUM(VALUE(MID(0&A1,LARGE(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+1,1)))}
```

Basically this is to assign each character with its index and then get the numeric value to sum up.  Please note this is an array formula.  Please click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together.

**REVISED:**

Here is the **array** formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) to extract two-digit numbers:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(0+("0"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(S‌​UBSTITUTE(LOWER(MID(‌​‌​A1,SEARCH("h)",A1)‌​-4,LEN(A1))),"h","")‌​,")","("),"(",REPT(" ",1000)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:20"))*2*1000-999,1000))),0))}
```

[image]

What this does is to massage the text first by removing unnecessary content, remove `h` wording and convert `)` to 999 blanks.  Then you can extract numbers and add up.  `IFERROR` will made the anything not numbers to 0.  Hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this already works for single numbers 1, 2, .... How to change the formula to also cover numbers >=10? (I updated my question). Furthermore it should only cover numbers with postfix "h". Does this work?

Comment: @Chris, so from your example, the result should be 16 not 9, correct? Also, you mention only to retrieve numbers with postfix h, will those numbers be surrounded with parentheses `()`?

Comment: yes, it should be 16 in the example. And yes also for your second comment: he mask for the relevant numbers is <"(" x "h)">.

Comment: @Chris, I have revised my answer with new formula for you to try.  Please let me know how that goes.

Comment: the revised formula works much better now! But there is one issue with recognizing postfix "h)". 
Examples: 
"...(2)...(14h)..(1)" results in 15. 
"...(2h)...(14h)..(1)" results in 17. 
"...(2)...(14)..(1h)" results in 1. 
So all numbers from beginning of first "h)" were recognized and also these without "h" (which is wrong).

Comment: @Chris, I thought you said it will always have `(xh)` and the `x` is the number to be extracted and that is why.

Comment: Correct, so any other should be ignored, but not (xh). The problem is, that non-number contents inside brackets, which appear after the first (xh), will result in an error: like "...(2h)...test (comment)..."

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean from the last comment.  Do you mind to provide me an example and I can tweak the code?  Or you can add to your question if that is easier.

Comment: I updated my question (UPDATE2) and example (added "(draft"))

Comment: @Chris, I just updated my **REVISED** answer with the array formula (sorry you have to use array formula this time).  Try and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155998/discussion-between-chris-and-ian0411).

Comment: The last version in chat above works well: {=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(0+("0"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(MID(‌​A1,SEARCH("h)",A1)-4,LEN(A1))),"h",""),")","("),"(",REPT(" ",1000)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:20"))*2*1000-999,1000))),0))} (array formula!). 
One last improvement would be to have more than 1000 characters. 
@ian0411, Thanks for this solution!! :)

Comment: Thanks, @Chris.  I just updated my answer to reflect the correct one that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this is not in any way elegant, however it is working. I do not have time to run through the logic here right now (might edit it in later though) but essentially it is a load of search index logic.

I have Used 5 columns for each formula which assumes a maximum of 5 values but you can adjust this as needed by dragging the formula over more columns as it will begin looking for the next "(?h)" after the previous column's found value.

Red cell formula: `=SEARCH("(?h)",$A1)&" - "&SEARCH("h)",$A1)`

Orange cell formula: `=SEARCH("(?h)",$A1,MID(B1,SEARCH("- ",B1)+2,LEN(B1)-(SEARCH("- ",B1)+1))*1)&" - "&SEARCH("h)",$A1,MID(B1,SEARCH("- ",B1)+2,LEN(B1)-(SEARCH("- ",B1)+1))+1)`

Yellow cell formula: `=MID($A1,LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" - ",B1))+1,((MID(B1,SEARCH("- ",B1)+2,LEN(B1)-(SEARCH("- ",B1)))*1)-(LEFT(B1,SEARCH(" - ",B1))*1))-1)*1`

Green cell formula: `=SUMIF(G1:K1,">="&0)`

[image]