# Sum several values between brackets separated by line break in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to sum several values between brackets that are separated by line breaks in the same cell, where there are other characters.

I have tried the suggested formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113975/how-to-sum-several-bracket-surrounded-numbers-of-a-single-cell-with-excel-formul) but it didn't work.

I have macOS Montery and I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.16.27 (201012)

My Excel cell looks like this (I have many other cells, and the number of lines differ in each cell):

[image]

So in this case, the sum wanted is 1+2+2+3+1+3

Thank you,

Najoua

Comment: Please post the formula you are using here.

Comment: @SJR here is the used formula `=SUM(VALUE(MID(0&A1,LARGE(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+1,1)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=SUM(--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"(",")"},CHAR(10)),,2))
```

Or, for Excel 2013 (and higher):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",")"),CHAR(10),")"),")","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 3 = 2]"))
```

Comment: The second formula worked for me, thanks a lot @JvdV

Comment: can I be greedy and ask if I can sum only those in red or only those in black ?

Comment: @Najoua you'd need to use an udf for that meaning some vba script

Comment: Oh I believe that needs much learning … Thanks a lot @JvdV